# Editing ~/.vnc/xstartup to launch Xfce on VNC server

Tags: unity, xubuntu, xfce, remote-desktop, vnc

I have been following [this linode tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/remote-desktop/using-vnc-to-operate-a-desktop-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Except that I want to use Xfce instead of Unity.

On the last line of the `~/.vnc/xstartup` file is says to add:

```
gnome-session &
```

What should I put for Xfce?

Answer (score 10):

Normally to start the Xfce session from the console, you should put:

```
xfce4-session
```

More [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xfce4-session), but I'm not sure about using this with VNC. Remember that first you have to install Xfce, in first step from Your link (Installing a Desktop and VNC on your Linode) change:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

to:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Comment: @frlan: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/645200/revisions) and also review the spelling and grammar of the questions or answers you're editing in the future?  As now you're creating additional work for the reviewers instead of less work...  **;-)**

Answer (score 8):

After installing tightvnserver and xfce4 (apt-get on ubi) run "vncserver" once to create `~/.vnc/xstartup` file.  move it, and create a new xstartup file and put this in it.

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

- Save it (:wq! in vi, ctrl +x in nano)
- kill the running one (should be :1  - cmd = vncserver -kill :1) and the restart it ..
- when you connect with vnc client (:1 = 5901, :2, 5902, etc) you should have xfce4 startup (dont forget xfce4-goodies package)

There's a nice write-up at DigitalOcean website [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: I'm following DigitalOcean's guide but found no option to save the file, how to save it?

Comment: @Niminim This is probably too late, but in case you are using `nano`, you can save with `ctrl + x`.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi - updated with your tip for nano (i use vi :)_ )